# Google Drive API for PHP - How to connect?

Tags: php, drive

I am just trying to connect my PHP with Google API. My aim is to fetch a particular folder's content and show them as feeds in my site. So for a base I am trying to pull the kind of file of my drive. I am struck. Here is my code.

```
<?php  
require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';   
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$client = new Google_Client(); $client->setApplicationName("My Application"); 
$client->setDeveloperKey("<mykey>");
     $service = new Google_DriveService($client);

  $optParams = array('fields' => 'kind');   $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

  foreach ($results['files'] as $item) {
    print($item['kind'].'<br>');   
} 
?>
```

When I execute this, I get the following error,

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message
>   'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?fields=kind&key=:
>   (403) Insufficient permissions for this file' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ccl\gdapi\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php:66
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ccl\gdapi\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php(36):
>   Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ccl\gdapi\google-api-php-client\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php(177):
>   Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ccl\gdapi\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\Google_DriveService.php(465):
>   Google_ServiceResource->__call('list', Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ccl\gdapi\google-api-php-client\test.php(12):
>   Google_FilesServiceResource->listFiles(Array) #4 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ccl\gdapi\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php
>   on line 66

I gave proper key. Kindly help me. Thank you